# Leverage values in specific rows with date difference (3 months, 6, year)- eg 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th - for a given number of iterations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge dataset of accounts with date ranges and previously left joined monthly history of payments, with  payment amounts, **frequency of transactions** (1 stands for every month, 3 - every three months, 6 - half year, 12 - once in a year) and **number of times such transaction repeats**. If **payment frequency is 12 and Npayments is 4**, this means that the account holder paid this specific amount **once in a year for four years**...

Having the current dataset for a sample account, can you please advise how can i change and leverage amount values for such dates - row 26 for example, and after it row 38 and row 50 - where [Reg_cash] (which is just [Amount] spread across rows) should be 351,84 instead of 321,84?

I am not sure how recursive CTE fits in here, and I also was thinking of using replace() with select but don't know how to choose specific rows... I can't think of anything else so far, please help..

Here is the dataset with partial history of records for an account as an image, I am not sure how to best represent the whole story of 61 payments here... Thanks!

this is raw data:

```
    [Payment_date][Trans_date][Amount][Reg_cash][Trans_frequency][N_of_trans][rn]
    
    13.03.2018  NULL      0       NULL  NULL    1
    23.03.2018  23.03.2018  321,84  1    1      2
    13.04.2018  13.04.2018  321,84  1    1      3
    13.05.2018  13.05.2018  321,84  1    10     4
    13.06.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    5
    13.07.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    6
    13.08.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    7
    13.09.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    8
    13.10.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    9
    13.11.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    10
    13.12.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    11
    13.01.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    12
    13.02.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    13
    13.03.2019  13.03.2019  351,84  12   4      14
    13.04.2019  13.04.2019  321,84  1    11     15
    13.05.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    16
    13.06.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    17
    13.07.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    18
    13.08.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    19
    13.09.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    20
    13.10.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    21
    13.11.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    22
    13.12.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    23
    13.01.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    24
    13.02.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    25
    13.03.2020  NULL     321,84    12     4     26
    13.04.2020  13.04.2020  321,84  1     11    27
    13.05.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    28
    13.06.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    29
    13.07.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    30
    13.08.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    31
    13.09.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    32
    13.10.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    33
    13.11.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    34
    13.12.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    35
    13.01.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    36
    13.02.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    37
    13.03.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    38
    13.04.2021  13.04.2021  321,84  1   11      39
    13.05.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    40
    13.06.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    41
    13.07.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    42
    13.08.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    43
    13.09.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    44
    13.10.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    45
    13.11.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    46
    13.12.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    47
    13.01.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    48
    13.02.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    49
    13.03.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    50
    13.04.2022  13.04.2022  321,84  1   11  51
    13.05.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    52
    13.06.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    53
    13.07.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    54
    13.08.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    55
    13.09.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    56
    13.10.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    57
    13.11.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    58
    13.12.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    59
    13.01.2023  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    60
    13.02.2023  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    61
```

and so on for other accounts...

Here is the desired output:

```
[Payment_date][Trans_date][Amount][Reg_cash][Trans_frequency][N_of_trans][rn]
        
        13.03.2018  NULL      0       NULL  NULL    1
        23.03.2018  23.03.2018  321,84  1    1      2
        13.04.2018  13.04.2018  321,84  1    1      3
        13.05.2018  13.05.2018  321,84  1    10     4
        13.06.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    5
        13.07.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    6
        13.08.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    7
        13.09.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    8
        13.10.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    9
        13.11.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    10
        13.12.2018  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    11
        13.01.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    12
        13.02.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    13
        13.03.2019  13.03.2019  351,84  12   4      14
        13.04.2019  13.04.2019  321,84  1    11     15
        13.05.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    16
        13.06.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    17
        13.07.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    18
        13.08.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    19
        13.09.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    20
        13.10.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    21
        13.11.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    22
        13.12.2019  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    23
        13.01.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    24
        13.02.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    25
        13.03.2020  13.03.2020   351,84    12     4     26
        13.04.2020  13.04.2020  321,84  1     11    27
        13.05.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    28
        13.06.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    29
        13.07.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    30
        13.08.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    31
        13.09.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    32
        13.10.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    33
        13.11.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    34
        13.12.2020  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    35
        13.01.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    36
        13.02.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    37
        13.03.2021  13.03.2021   351,84   NULL  NULL    38
        13.04.2021  13.04.2021  321,84  1   11      39
        13.05.2021  NULL     321,84   NULL  NULL    40
        13.06.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    41
        13.07.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    42
        13.08.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    43
        13.09.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    44
        13.10.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    45
        13.11.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    46
        13.12.2021  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    47
        13.01.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    48
        13.02.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    49
        13.03.2022  13.03.2022  351,84  NULL    NULL    50
        13.04.2022  13.04.2022  321,84  1   11  51
        13.05.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    52
        13.06.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    53
        13.07.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    54
        13.08.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    55
        13.09.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    56
        13.10.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    57
        13.11.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    58
        13.12.2022  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    59
        13.01.2023  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    60
        13.02.2023  NULL    321,84  NULL    NULL    61
```

stop.

I started with this, but it generates just dates only for the first iteration (so maybe i could do a further join somehow but unsure), and ignores 3rd and 4th yearly payments...

```
select a.*
, case when [TRANS_FREQUENCY] = '1' then dateadd(month,1,[Trans_date])
when [TRANS_FREQUENCY] = '3' then dateadd(month,3,[Trans_date])
when [TRANS_FREQUENCY] = '6' then dateadd(day,6,[Trans_date])
when [TRANS_FREQUENCY] = '10' then dateadd(month,10,[Trans_date])
when [TRANS_FREQUENCY] = '12'  then dateadd(month,12,[Trans_date])
when [TRANS_FREQUENCY] = '31' then dateadd(month,31,[Trans_date])
end as [Date]
from (
select [AAGRNUM],[Trans_date],[AMOUNT],[TRANS_FREQUENCY],[NO_OF_RENTALS],ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [AAGRNUM],[Trans_date] ASC) AS [rn]
from [dbo].[ARENTAL2-scope] 
where aagrnum = 'ACAV003174' --or aagrnum = 'AAXA004478'
) a
order by [AAGRNUM],[Trans_date]
```

Comment: Sounds like you and [Adriana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11005801/adriana) are working in the same class and same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62563893/2029983). They were asked to provide their expected results and their attempts. Could you please do the same? Also, please ensure that the data is well formatted; otherwise it's very hard for us to consume. The above is not well aligned, so please do take the time to ensure it is. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks! I added the expected results...

Comment: Just needs your attempt(s) and them to be **well** formatted then, @Sandra. :)

Comment: okay, i finally found a solution that works! https://alessandroalpi.blog/2013/07/04/repeating-rows-based-on-a-value-in-a-different-column/